# What is a swift un keyed container?

Tags: swift

Hello could someone please explain what is a UnkeyedContainer I cant understand what is exactly from the swift documentation?
thanks

Comment: It's Apple's approach in archiving and unarchiving an object as an XML file.

Comment: A quick google search gave me this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unkeyeddecodingcontainer

Answer (score 3):

Swift uses 3 types of containers for its encoding/decoding system:

- **Keyed containers** appropriate for holding multiple values keyed by the given key type.
- **Single value containers**: appropriate for holding a single primitive value.
- **Unkeyed containers**: appropriate for holding multiple unkeyed values.

You can use the unkeyed container to encode a set of values for example. The keyed container on the other hand can be used to encode things like dictionaries (key:value pairs).

---

**Reference documentation** (July 2021): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/encoding_decoding_and_serialization